# Why doesn't textarea.selectionStart work on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom-events

This has gotten to the point of absolute frustration.  We are trying to write some js that will insert text at a specific location in the text associated with a textarea.  It seems like it should be simple but so far we haven't figured it out.

What complicates our process is that we have a floating menu from which you make selections about what you want to insert.  So the sequence is:

- position to the desired insert location in the textarea.  Using a debugger breakpoint, Visual Studio debugger indicates that the textarea object has `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` defined as numbers with the correct values.  If at that break, you try and write js that accesses `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` you get undefined (which doesn't make sense but there are a lot of postings here that say everyone else has the same issue)
- now we position to the floating menu which is nothing more than a div wrapper on a table where the td elements call a function to insert text).  If we click exactly on the td element, the text will get inserted where it belongs.  If at anytime we click outside the td element but inside the menu, document selection gets reset to the beginning of the text area and we insert at the wrong location.
- we have tried trapping the `onclick` event chain associated with the menu and there is nothing obvious going on that would cause document selection to change but it does nonetheless.
- we have tried a variety of workarounds where we put an `onClick` on the textarea itself and remember the current range for the textarea but that always ends up at the front of the buffer.

So in simple terms:  why doesn't `createTextRange` and document selection behave in a rational manner on IE and what is the workaround?

What does jQuery do that works around this issue since the most common answer to the postings about this seems to be use jQuery?

Comment: You can check how jQuery does it yourself by reading its source: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: My canned recommendation to everything related to ranges/selections: **[use Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will insert at caret.

```
function insertAtCaret ( areaId, text ) {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId),
        scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop,
        strPos = 0,
        range, front, back,
        br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
        "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        strPos = range.text.length;
    }
    else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
    back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
    txtarea.value=front+text+back;
    strPos = strPos + text.length;
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
        range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (br == "ff") {
        txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
        txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
        txtarea.focus();
    }
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
};
```

I originally got it from an answer here on SO.

Comment: i tried it and it always inserts 1 character from the end of the textarea which leads me to believe that something is changing document selection in between the time we set our insert point and the time the text gets inserted.

Comment: are you modifying the text in the textarea before using this method?

Comment: You are right, it isn't working 100% in IE, for me it is inserting it not quite where the caret is, usually farther down in the text area.